# Event on a button click when the button is generated after the load of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my code, I duplicate a piece of html code with jquery for some reasons. In this piece of code, I have a button. The initial button, when it's clicked, displays something in the page. But the problem is that my new button, generated in jquery, doesn't run the event. It does nothing.

My button (in a table) :

```
<button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in afficher_itk" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

The way it's duplicated :

```
    var table = document.getElementById("table_cultures");

    var row = document.getElementById('clonedRow');
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

    table.appendChild(clone);
```

The "onclick" function :

```
$(".afficher_itk").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Use .on("click", function()... instead of .click

Comment: @Riddell I tried with `.on` as you said and as the post said but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think this can't work because it's not a dynamic creation but a creation after page loading ... so it's not the same case

Comment: It's exactly the same case, Riddell just gave you the wrong code to use. Try the delegated signature for the `on()` method, as per the question I linked.

Comment: Eg. `$('#table_cultures').on('click', '.afficher_itk', function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My bad, you were right, sorry for it. It works because of you, thanks :)

Comment: Ahh sorry yes I forgot delegated signature. I knew it was along those lines. Glad you fixed it.